Why does the simple python server / javascript socketio communication fail?
I have a simple flask-socketio server that emits a stream of floats and serves an html file with a javascript socket.io listener.  The initial connection appears to immediately disconnect, the server does continue to emit messages (I monitored using Wireshark), but nothing appears on the webpage.
Versions:

OS: Windows 11
python: 3.11.9
Flask 3.0.3
Werkzeug 3.0.2
python-socketio: 5.11.2
python-engineio: 4.9.0
simple-websocket: 1.0.0
javascript socket.io: 4.0.1
Browser: Chrome Version 123.0.6312.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I tried with earlier socketio / engineio and Javascript socket.io releases because in the docs https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#version-compatibility docs  it says below the compatibility table: "Can connect to other Socket.IO servers that are compatible with the JavaScript Socket.IO 1.x and 2.x releases. Work to support release 3.x is in progress."  No valid version combination works with my program, however.
Here is the server code:
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS

import threading
import time
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app,logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
socketio.on("connection", print("Connected "));
socketio.on("connect_error", lambda err: print("connect_error due to " + err.message));
socketio.on("disconnect", print("Disconnected"));

def emit_floats():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)  # Emit a float every second. Adjust the timing as needed.
        float_value = random.random()  
        socketio.emit("new_float", {"value": float_value}, namespace="/test")
        print(f"Emitted {float_value}")  #

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the thread that emits floats.
    threading.Thread(target=emit_floats, daemon=True).start()
    socketio.run(app,debug=True)

Here is the html/javascript file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask SocketIO Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" referrer="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
        console.log(document.domain + ':' + location.port)
        
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('Websocket connected!');
        });
        
        socket.on("new_float", function(msg) {
            console.log('Received float: ' + msg.value);
            document.getElementById("floatValue").innerHTML = "Latest Float: " + msg.value;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask-SocketIO Float Emitter</h1>
    <div id="floatValue">Latest Float: Waiting for data...</div>
</body>
</html>

The server console says this upon starting up:
$ python server.py
Server initialized for eventlet.
Connected
Disconnected
 * Restarting with stat
Server initialized for eventlet.
Connected
Disconnected
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 951-349-505
(5132) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(5132) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 62020)
gLMwdIe6pi1wsgCJAAAA: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': 'gLMwdIe6pi1wsgCJAAAA', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 20000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2024 13:05:42] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OxeW-QN HTTP/1.1" 200 278 0.000000
gLMwdIe6pi1wsgCJAAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 0/test,
gLMwdIe6pi1wsgCJAAAA: Sending packet MESSAGE data 4/test,"Unable to connect"
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2024 13:05:42] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OxeW-ZH&sid=gLMwdIe6pi1wsgCJAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 219 0.000000
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2024 13:05:42] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OxeW-ZL&sid=gLMwdIe6pi1wsgCJAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 208 0.001004
emitting event "new_float" to all [/test]
Emitted 0.19877135766801945
(5132) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 62019)
(5132) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 62023)
(5132) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 62024)
gLMwdIe6pi1wsgCJAAAA: Received request to upgrade to websocket
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2024 13:05:43] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OxeW-ZQ&sid=gLMwdIe6pi1wsgCJAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 181 0.302727
gLMwdIe6pi1wsgCJAAAA: Upgrade to websocket successful
emitting event "new_float" to all [/test]
Emitted 0.7647208741003735
emitting event "new_float" to all [/test]
Emitted 0.004322528800467906

The webpage (localhost:5000) shows this:

The Network tab on the browser console says (interestingly):

First "OK"
Then: "44/test,"Unable to connect"
Then: "6"
Then: 

It appears the request to switch protocols is still "pending".
I read a post that says Chrome needs wss instead of ws websocket protocol and that I should create a self-signed X.509 certificate and add it to the application, but on the other hand I have a simple node.js/javascript two-way chat program that works just fine with Chrome and no certificate.
Moved the app to an Ubuntu VM with Firefox as browser.  Same issue.
So where am I going wrong?
